# USB inf file can not pass the signature validation

Tags: usb, driver, digital-signature, inf

I'm trying to sign my USB INF file by Inf2Cat.exe command, but the signing result is always fail. The fail reason as below

```
Errors:
22.9.10: usbser.sys in [virtualcomcopyfilesection] is missing 
from [SourceDisksFiles] section in \tpp_test.inf;
driver may not sign correctly until this is resolved.
```

I used the instruct "Inf2Cat.exe /v /driver:%~dp0 /os:XP_X86,XP_X64" to sign the USB INF file, and the USB INF file as below.

How to fix this problem?

```
[Version] 
Signature="$Windows NT$" 
Class=Ports 
ClassGuid={4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} 
Provider=%MFG% 
;LayoutFile = layout.inf
CatalogFile.nt = DEVICE.cat
CatalogFile.ntx86 = DEVICE_X86.cat
CatalogFile.ntia64 = DEVICE_IA64.cat
CatalogFile.ntamd64 = DEVICE_AMD64.cat
DriverVer=07/23/2009,1.0


[SourceDisksFiles]
; Use inbox driver

[SourceDisksNames]
; Use inbox driver


[Manufacturer] 
%MFG%=MFG, NT, NTx86, NTia64, NTamd64

[MFG]
%DEVICE%=DEVICE_USBCDC, USB\VID_1234&PID_4321

[MFG.NT] 
%DEVICE%=DEVICE_USBCDC, USB\VID_1234&PID_4321

[MFG.NTx86] 
%DEVICE%=DEVICE_USBCDC, USB\VID_1234&PID_4321

[MFG.NTia64] 
%DEVICE%=DEVICE_USBCDC, USB\VID_1234&PID_4321

[MFG.NTamd64] 
%DEVICE%=DEVICE_USBCDC, USB\VID_1234&PID_4321

[DestinationDirs]
VirtualCOMCopyFileSection = 12  ;%windir%\system32\drivers
DefaultDestDir = 12


;************************************
;* NT
;************************************
;************************************
;* DEVICE

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NT]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=VirtualCOMCopyFileSection
AddReg=VirtualCOMAddReg 

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NT.Services] 
include=mdmcpq.inf
AddService = usbser, 0x00000002, Service_Inst

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NT.HW]
include=mdmcpq.inf


;************************************
;* NTx86
;************************************
;************************************
;* DEVICE

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTx86]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=VirtualCOMCopyFileSection
AddReg=VirtualCOMAddReg 

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTx86.Services] 
include=mdmcpq.inf
AddService = usbser, 0x00000002, Service_Inst 

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTx86.HW]
include=mdmcpq.inf


;************************************
;* NTia64
;************************************
;************************************
;* DEVICE

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTia64]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=VirtualCOMCopyFileSection
AddReg=VirtualCOMAddReg 

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTia64.Services] 
include=mdmcpq.inf
AddService = usbser, 0x00000002, Service_Inst

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTia64.HW]
include=mdmcpq.inf


;************************************
;* NTamd64
;************************************
;************************************
;* DEVICE

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTamd64]
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=VirtualCOMCopyFileSection
AddReg=VirtualCOMAddReg 

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTamd64.Services] 
include=mdmcpq.inf
AddService = usbser, 0x00000002, Service_Inst

[DEVICE_USBCDC.NTamd64.HW]
include=mdmcpq.inf


[VirtualCOMCopyFileSection] 
usbser.sys,,,0x20


[VirtualCOMAddReg] 
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern 
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,usbser.sys 
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider" 


[Service_Inst] 
DisplayName = %Serial.SvcDesc% 
ServiceType = 1 ; SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER 
StartType = 3 ; SERVICE_DEMAND_START 
ErrorControl = 1 ; SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL 
ServiceBinary = %12%\usbser.sys 
LoadOrderGroup = Base 


[Strings] 
MFG = "Test" 
DEVICE = "Test device"
DISC_NAME = "USB Driver"
Serial.SvcDesc = "MFG USB Virtual COM"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
CopyFiles=VirtualCOMCopyFileSection
```

need to be changed as

```
CopyFiles=FakeModemCopyFileSection
```

And the statement

```
[VirtualCOMCopyFileSection] 
usbser.sys,,,0x20
```

need to be changed as

```
[FakeModemCopyFileSection] 
;USBSER.sys,,,0x20
```